# static website using docker nginx doesn't update automatically after rebuilding image

Tags: docker, nginx, web-development-server

I am a beginner with `nginx`. I am using the [docker nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) image to build a static website.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The files copied in the container are a simple `index.html` with some `css/js`.

Here is what I did on my laptop:

1. I built a first webiste image and executed the container on my laptop. I could see the website by hitting `http://localhost:port`.
2. I changed the `index.html`, rebuilt the image and executed again the container on my laptop. I could see the changes added in `index.html` on the website by hitting `http://localhost:port`.

I did exactly the same process on a remote virtual machine but this time, I cannot see the changes I made `index.html` after rebuilding the image (step 2).

Here are my environments details:

Laptop:

```
MacOS High Serria 10.13.1
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
```

Virtual Machine:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
Docker version 1.12.5, build 047e51b/1.12.5
```

Any idea what could made this happen? Do I have to fine-tune something in `nginx` config files? Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you open the webpage in the remote machine?

Comment: `http://host-ip:port`